# How Do I Rollout WP-Cache To 1000 WordPress Blogs?

Tags: wordpress, rollout

My client has 1000 WordPress blogs hosted on a server for customers. Each one is in its own domain through cpanel and SuPHP, running in CGI mode on Apache2.2. Now he wants me (I'm the PHP programmer) to get WP-Cache loaded out on each of these blogs and not just activated, but enabled. He also wants the timeout value set to 2 days instead of the default setting.

I have root on LAMP.

What is the preferred way to roll out an update to each blog such that on a page view, it sees if WP-Cache is enabled or not. If not, it needs to copy it out from a central source, activate it, and then enable it along with the different timeout value being used.

Comment: I'd like a chance to respond if I may. It involves programming. I may have to crack open a WordPress file and use stuff from the WP Codex. The guys on ServerFault may know a thing or two about Perl and Bash commands, and system performance, but not a whole lot about programming. So this is why I posted this here.

Answer (score 1):

A way, maybe not the best way, is to write a script to copy the wp-cache plugin to *every* wp-content/pulugins folder. Then run another script that will go and modify every DB entry for it enabling it.

If not done correctly this can be devastating as it hits customer db's.

However, one thing to note is wp-cache has a history of killing other plugins. So, if you go in and add this plugin to everyone's wordpress it might hurt there experience if it hurts another plugin they have installed thus increasing support costs as people might be emailing trying to figure out what broke.

I take it this is being done to work on performance issues. Is it possible to maybe do some type of server caching outside of wordpress?

edit: after reading Joes comment I concur with him. Didn't even cross my mind.

Comment: In this particular case, the customers are all running the same plugins in a package deal, and none deviate from this.